# Using ClickOnce (or similar) for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, deployment, web-deployment

I'm looking for a way to providing users (administrators) of a web application to automatically (meaning it's opt-in to update, but the installation should be automatic when started) update said web application when new versions are released.

The reason why I want an automatic approach is that I want the users to be able to update the web application while it's running remotely, without having to gain physical access to the machine (including RDP).

I could of course write my own code for this, but I would prefer to use something like ClickOnce that has been around for a while. Is it possible to use ClickOnce for this?
Or is there an alternative for ASP.NET applications that I have not been able to find?

It is important that it's the user that does the update and not me, so I don't think WebDeployment is the way to go, but I'm willing to listen to scenarios where this would work.

The users are not system administrators, so I want this to be as fool proof as possible.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, ASP.NET 2.0 (.NET 3.5). If a solution requires switching to version 4, this is possible, but not preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future reference, I would probably look into the Self Updating Site Using NuGet by Phil Haack at http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/15/building-a-self-updating-site-using-nuget.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I ended up with using Web config transforms and Deployment Packages with Web Deploy, along with a custom configuration wizard for some of the trickier parts of the Web.config.

This doesn't feel optimal at all, but it's what we did.

Comment: What makes you say it's not optimal?

Comment: It was a bit more technical advanced than I was looking for. I think Deployment Packages are great, but I was looking for something more end-user friendly. In the end though, it is probably for the best.